# How to Store the game score in android cocos2d

Tags: android, cocos2d

I calculates the score in game project using android cocos2d, in that game after finishing the first level it goes to the next level, so i want to store that first level score and also add next level scores. how can i store that scores in android-cocos2d.

Comment: I'm not sure about android version, but in cocos2d-x there is a method named `CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath()`. using that method I can create and save data into a file.

Comment: can i use shared preferences here or any other way is there for storing that game score

Comment: As I said I didn't tried anything with android, so I don't even know what are you talking about! you can also check [OpenFeint](openfeint.com/) it has a good framework to save/share scores written in java.